# Stripping a block of text from a file using python

Tags: python

I have to basically strip out a block of text from file1. The file1 is huge of many thousand lines (~3GB size). The block looks as below,

```
line 1
line 2
<pattern1> {
...
...
...
}
<pattern2> {
...
...
...
}
```

I am basically trying to write out the blocks of line between the curly braces "{}" in the file and I am trying to pattern match for each of that entry (pattern1, pattern2) while reading the line. I am giving a list of the patterns through another file (file2).
So I was thinking of something like below for my logic (not the code but the idea) but was not confident. Can someone clarify what would be the best way to approach this?

- Open the file2 and get the string pattern to be matched.
- Open the file1 and start searching for each line for the string pattern from file2.
- Once found, enable the flag and start writing the lines between the braces to an output file (say file3).
- Once the closing braces are encountered unset the flag and stop the writing to the file (file3).

Comment: Is there only one pattern in file2?

Comment: Are there any nested braces?

Comment: Nope there are multiple patterns in file2 and thats why I called it as pattern1/pattern2 (eg. like 100 such patterns) and yes there are nested braces within the block which I am trying to write out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposal is simple to understand and implement.  This also makes it easy to debug, maintain, and update.  Yes, this is a good approach to use.

```
start_pattern_list =   # Make this a list of all the patterns from file2
stop_pattern = "}\n"
out_flag == False
for line in <input file>:
    if '<' in line:
        if any(p in line for p in start_pattern_list):
            out_flag = True     # Turn on output
    if out_flag:
        out_file.write(line)
    if stop_pattern in line:
        out_flag = False    # Turn off output
```

This works for simple files: no nested braces, the input trigger (pattern) appears only as a pattern (not embedded within the braces).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. But I have a follow up question. Looking at the solution the logic seems to be iterating over the big file (file1) again and again based on the patterns from file2. So basically I am reading the huge file1 multiple times. Is that ok? Do you suggest any other run time efficient code?

Comment: 100 file reads is not good.  Instead, make a list of the patterns; compare each to the input lines.  Even better if you can find a better trigger for a pattern, such as the "less than" I coded into the update.

Comment: I was trying to extend the above code for the scenario when there are nested braces inside my search blocks. So I was trying to implement a counter of finding a forward and backward brace. When the difference of those were came to 0 I stopped recording to write into the file. But I am not able to effectively translate this logic into the code. Could you elaborate how will the approach be if we parse the block of text based on the braces instead of a fixed start and stop pattern?

Comment: That should be another question posted.  Please include the code that isn't working for you, and we'll give it a shot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965024/stripping-a-block-of-text-using-python?noredirect=1#comment69139652_40965024