# Stripping a block of text using python

Tags: python

As requested in the other thread, I have given below the code which I am using to strip the block of text from a file which has the following format. As listed before the problem which I am trying to solve by this code is the following,

1. To parse a block of text from a file(file1) using the patterns created out of another file(file2). Both file1 and file2 provided as command line arguments.
2. The logic to determine the block of text is by counting the '{' & '}' braces within that section (as the block of text contains lot of braces within that section). One thing to note though is that there is a 'Begin' & 'End' lines wrapping the block text (ie., braces). In my code I have tried to track both of these as the file format of file1 may sometimes not have 'Begin'/'End' lines but the braces will always be there.

   I need suggestions on how to improve this code for runtime and also for brevity (code optimization). Please note that the file1 is a huge file containing hundred thousands of lines but the file2 is small which is about 100s of line. I have tried to add comments wherever possible inside the code to make it more easier to read.

   The file1 format will look something like below

   ```
   /* Begin : abcxyz*/
   cell ("pattern1") {
   /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   /* Comment lines */
   /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   line 1
   line 2 {
   }
   line 3
   }
   /* End : abcxyz*/
   ```

   The actual code is listed below,

   ```
   import sys # Module to work with argv parameters
   import re # Module to work with regular expressions

   in_file = sys.argv[1] # Setting the first argument as file1.
   pattern_file = sys.argv[2] # Setting the second argument as file2 (containing the patterns to be parsed in file1).

   patterns = [] # Creating a empty list for populating the pattern details.
   with open (pattern_file, 'r') as file2: # Opening the file2 in read mode.
       for pattern in sorted(set(file2.readlines())): # Sorting and making the pattern list unique while reading each pattern.
           patterns.append(pattern.rstrip('\n')) # Stripping the newline character and building the pattern array set.

   out_flag = False
   forward_brace = 0
   backward_brace = 0
   scope_count = 0
   out_file = open ("file3", 'w')
   with open (in_file, 'r') as in_lib: # Opens the input file(file1) for reading.
       for line in in_lib.readlines(): # Reads the entire content of the file1 in the form of list
           # Creates a generator expression; tries to get the first match from the file1 based on the pattern list
           # Once the begin block is found, the flag to write the output file is set to True
           if any(p in line for p in patterns) and 'Begin ' in line:
               forward_brace = backward_brace = 0
               out_flag = True
           # For all the lines other than 'Begin' statement, the brace count is calculated.
           # The brace count is kept track for determining the scope of the cell block.
           else:
               # Matches any line starting with '/*' or '*' to avoid counting the brace for scope determination.
               if any(re.match(r, line) for r in ['^\s*/','^\s*[*]']):
                   out_file.write(line)
                   continue
               else:
                   forward_brace += line.count('{')
                   backward_brace += line.count('}')
                   scope_count = forward_brace - backward_brace
           # Boolean check on flag performed for writing to the output file.
           # If the 'End ' block is arrived at then the out_flag is set to False.
           if out_flag:
               out_file.write(line)
               if 'End ' in line:
                   out_flag = False
           # Once the end of the scope block is arrived at ie., brace count is 0 and
           # also flag is set to False, the tracking variables are reset for next cell.
           if scope_count == 0 and not (out_flag):
               forward_brace = backward_brace = 0
               out_flag = False

   out_file.close()
   ```

Comment: *"I need suggestions on how to improve this code"* - that is not on topic. If this is **working code**, see [codereview.se]. If not, give a [mcve] of a specific issue not just a code dump.

Comment: I was asked to share the entire code for my other question in another thread and hence copied the entire code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942798/stripping-a-block-of-text-from-a-file-using-python/40943019?noredirect=1#comment69120835_40943019 The code is actually small and it became big with all the elaborate comments.

Comment: @Sreeder, if the code isn't working, you should still give an example or two of the failure.  From your previous posting, I understood that your brace-counting logic doesn't work.  In this posting, it sounds like that logic *does* work, but you have trouble picking up the **End** line.

Comment: Also, will the **Begin** and **End** always be properly paired?  If so, you can pick them up with another flag.  Does the **End** always come immediately after the closing brace, or can there be intervening text?  If the latter, what do you have to do with it?

Comment: Yes over the last couple of days, the code started working as expected. So I modified my problem statement from issue to improvement in the code review section. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes the Begin and End are always paired. The End will come immediately after the final closing brace.