# Strip out block of text from a file into new file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need help in striping out blocks of text from a file into separate files.

Example:

```
ltm data-group internal /Common/www_web {
    records {
        /images { }
        /images/ { }
        /test/common/ { }
    }
    type string
}
ltm monitor http /Common/data {
    adaptive disabled
    defaults-from /Common/http
    destination *:*
    interval 1
    ip-dscp 0
    recv "\{\"status\":\"UP\""
    recv-disable "\{\"status\":\"DOWN\""
    send {}
    time-until-up 0
    timeout 4
}
ltm profile http /Common/stage {
    adaptive disabled
    defaults-from /Common/http
    destination *:*
    interval 5
    ip-dscp 0
    recv "\{\"status\":\"UP\""
    recv-disable "\{\"status\":\"DOWN\""
    send "GET /proxy/test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: staging\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
    time-until-up 0
    timeout 16
}
```

I want to strip out each of the block into write it into a separate file, eg:

```
ltm data-group internal /Common/www_web {
    records {
        /images { }
        /images/ { }
        /test/common/ { }
    }
    type string
}
```

into a separate file.

```
ltm monitor http /Common/data {
    adaptive disabled
    defaults-from /Common/http
    destination *:*
    interval 1
    ip-dscp 0
    recv "\{\"status\":\"UP\""
    recv-disable "\{\"status\":\"DOWN\""
    send {}
    time-until-up 0
    timeout 4
}
```

and above block into a separate block and so on. So far I'm trying to find a regex to accomplish this and here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

regex = ur"(^ltm[\s\S]+^ltm)"
matches = re.search(regex, contents, re.MULTILINE)

if matches:
    print ("{match}".format(start = matches.start(), end = matches.end(), match = matches.group()))
```

So far this regex captures everything with in 'ltm' text. Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked into this [Stripping a block of text from a file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942798/stripping-a-block-of-text-from-a-file-using-python) but it didn't help much in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with simple list comprehension:

```
blocks = ["ltm " + s for s in re.split("^ltm ", contents)[1:]]
```

Also you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/VeI8V2/1) regular expression with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) *(but it will be much less efficient)*:

```
blocks = [match.group(0) for match in re.finditer("^ltm ((?!^ltm ).)*", contents, re.DOTALL)]
```

Or [this](https://regex101.com/r/GDZbvl/1) with [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
blocks = re.findall("(^ltm ((?!^ltm ).)*)", contents, re.DOTALL)
```

You can also achieve same without regular expressions using [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) *(clone of `str.index()` which doesn't throw an exception in case if substring haven't been found)*:

```
delimiter = "ltm "
blocks = []
index = contents.find(delimiter)
while index >= 0:
    new_index = contents.find(delimiter, index + 1)
    if not index or contents[index - 1] in {"\r", "\n"}:
        blocks.append(contents[index: new_index] if new_index > 0 else contents[index: ])
    index = new_index
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you what to name each file and you
can change this to fit what you need but this may help. 
The script scans line by line to find 'itm', if found will
make a new file with the name of the next block count.

```
def save_file_name(val):
    """returns a file named after the block count"""
    return f'block_{val}.txt'

# opens and stores said file.
file = open('ltm.txt', 'r')

# starting count.
count = 0

# The file that will contain each block.
new_file = open(save_file_name(str(count)), 'w')

# As @Olvin Roght had pointed out, its better to read
# the file line by line in this fashion.
for line in file:
    # The part that scans for the wanted keyword.
    if line.startswith('ltm'):
        # If True will fire this set of code.
        # add one to count.
        count += 1
        # Close the now finished file.
        new_file.close()
        # create and store a new file.
        # Important to note to turn count into a string
        new_file = open(save_file_name(str(count)), 'w')
        # write the line to the file.
        new_file.write(line)
    else:
        # And If not the wanted keyword, just write
        # to the still open file
        new_file.write(line)

# Always remeber to close the files that you open.
new_file.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: You can write even shorter: `for line in file`. Also will be better to check if there's space after `"ltm"` and is it on the start of new line. One more minor edit which will improve code readability would be renaming function `save_file()`.

Comment: Yes, good point, I should check for white spaces, but I can only go by what the OP has posted. And, 'for line in file', I thought that you needed 'readlines()' to go line by line thought a text file.

Comment: There's [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) which can be useful for you.

Comment: `file.readlines()` is equivalent of `list(file)` which means that it read whole file and split it by newlines into a list. So, when you write `for line in file.readlines()` you read all file immediately and work with list, but `for line in file` will read file line by line.

Comment: Your right, i have corrented my code, and thanks i've learned something too. I hope this help @Script_Junkie.

Comment: `save_file_name()` is better but not the best. I would recommend you to rename it with `get_file_name()` or delete this function at all and write `open(f'block_{count}.txt', 'a')`, which is more compact. By the way, why do you open files in append mode? It will duplicate content in file in case if script will be launched twice which is not good. I recommend you to use write mode.

Comment: Fix comment. I did not know that you could use string format as prams for open(). 'Why open files in append mode?' That was a misstake, thanks for pointing that out, and you are right,  that may duplicate the content. Thanks, again.